# How can I protect SPA in Blob Storage with an API?

Tags: azure, api, single-page-application, azure-ad-b2c

I am making a SPA with certification.
The SPA was then set up to be viewable on Blob Storage's static web site hosting.
At this time, we would like to protect the SPA with an API.
In other words, we want to obtain an access token for the API for SPA on the login screen to ensure security.
But I am a beginner and don't know much.
I am able to create a sign in screen and SPA.
Now I just need to restrict access through API, please let me know.

like this:
SignInPage(from ADB2C) → API → SPA(from React)

Comment: Try the sample here to [add auth to a SPA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-spa-app)

Answer (score 0):

You might benefit from reading and understand this article from Auth0 - https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/

Major take aways being:

Is the client a traditional web application executing on the server? [Use the Authorization Code Flow](https://auth0.com/docs/flows#authorization-code-flow).

Is the client a Single-Page Application (SPA)? [Use Authorization Code Flow with Proof Key for Code Exchange (PKCE)](https://auth0.com/docs/flows#authorization-code-flow-with-proof-key-for-code-exchange-pkce-).

Is the client a Single-Page Application (SPA) that doesn't need an access token? [Use the Implicit Flow with Form Post](https://auth0.com/docs/flows#implicit-flow-with-form-post).

Is the client the resource owner? You may use the [Client Credentials Flow](https://auth0.com/docs/flows#client-credentials-flow).

Is the client absolutely trusted with user credentials? You may use the
[Resource Owner Password Flow](https://auth0.com/docs/flows#resource-owner-password-flow)